# How to add objects to a class that I cannot edit

Tags: java, jframe, jmenuitem, jmenubar, stddraw

I am using the StdDraw.java library and I can't edit the file. I want to add various items to the `JFrame` such as `JMenu`, buttons and others without compromising the canvas and the `Jframe`.

I have tried something like 
`StdDraw.class.getMethods`"

Yet I can't seem to get it to work. It seems I can only use the methods inside the class and don't add some of my own or edit the ones already in.

The file is available online. How would I be able to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

[StdDraw.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdDraw.java.html) is a final class, if I am not mistaken. A final class cannot be extended. So you have two options:

1. You can directly use source then add your own attributes and compile it yourself, if the license permits this kind of usage.
2. You can encapsulate StdDraw.java class, with your own wrapper class and direct method calls using [Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance.

```
class MyClass extends JFrame {
    String myField = "";  //--- This is my own field!
}
```